# Why is my HTML aside block adding a superfluous ending paragraph break?

Tags: css, html

I have this markup:

### CSS

```
aside {
    color: cornsilk;
    font-family: 'Bookman Old School', Candara, Calibri, sans-serif;
}
```

### HTML

```
<aside style="margin:4px;padding:4px;border:1px solid forestgreen;">
    Some criticize <cite>Huckleberry Finn</cite> because it uses "the N word." While it <em>is</em> an ugly word, that is the way many people spoke in the time and place represented by this novel.

<p>Should it be censored out, or replaced with another word?</p>

<p><cite>Huckleberry Finn</cite> has been criticized from the "git-go" for various reasons (and in fact, Twain rather rejoiced at this than fretted, knowing that calls for his book to be banned would actually draw more attention to it and increase sales).</p>

    <p>Early on, some readers and reviewers were shocked, not by the novel's use of "the N word" (which they may not have considered objectionable or perhaps not even have really noticed, due to its ubiquitous usage throughout the country) but rather for its "low" subject matter and earthy humor, which was considered too crude and rough for "polite society" and sometimes for the very reason that Jim is portrayed sympathetically - as a real person with feelings and thoughts, and not as a minstrel show caricature.</p></aside>
```

As you can see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/tL4s1hjr/19/) (or, if you're an HTML/CSS guru, perhaps previsualize), there is a superfluous line or paragrpah break at the end of the section of HTML shown above. The other "asides"/annotations do not exhibit that behavior. Here's one of them:

```
<aside style="margin:4px;padding:4px;border:1px solid forestgreen;">
That is to say, 40-50 years ago at the time Twain wrote it, which was in the 1880s; in other words, the time period covered in "Huck Finn" is the 1830s and 1840s, between the War of 1812 and the Civil War.
</aside>
```

What need I do to evict the trailing break?

Comment: You’re probably referring to the default `margin-bottom` that the `p` element gets from the browser stylesheet. If you don’t like it – overwrite it.

Comment: @CBroe: So why does it work as desired in the other asides?

Comment: Hard tell with that overloaded fiddle (you should really make such examples smaller, so that they concentrate on the problem at hand, with the minimal code necessary to reproduce it) … probably because you don’t have `p` elements at the end of those.

Comment: FYI: ids must be unique within a document, and `aside` inside a `p` element is also not allowed … and there’s a couple of other errors in there as well, such as an opening `<span>` where a closing `</span>` should be instead, etc. – you should [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your HTML.

Comment: @B.ClayShannon because you have border styles on the `<aside>` and only one has `<p>` inside (the one you're complaining about).

Comment: @user2864740: _“HTML5 removes the restriction on IDs being unique with a document”_ – [nonsense](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute), same as your first comment about `</p>` …

Comment: @CBroe I was incorrect about the IDs. However, I stand by my recommendation *to **not** use </p> in HTML unless you wish for subtle surprises*. (I wish I hadn't removed the comment.) Try `<p>hello<div>hi</div>bye</p>foo`. The `</p>` is treated as `<p></p>` which is most certainly undesirable and most likely not expected. (The first paragraph is closed implicitly *before* the DIV - considering P's general hierarchical elements ill-advised and goes along with my suggestion to avoid the end-tag entirely.)

Comment: @user2864740 Although you are right about the possibility of not using the `</p>` (in most cases), I'd say that suggesting its avoidance is a mistake (and in some cases incorrect). As you state, the `<p>` is implicitly closed, and that makes the code invalid (the real problem). Imho claiming from that, that the end-tag should be avoided entirely is wrong, as it could result in invalid code too (eg: `<p>...<figure>...</figure>`). It would be better to close things where they need to be closed instead of leaving more work to the browser... and a tougher maintenance for the next developer

Comment: @user2864740: _“Try <p>hello<div>hi</div>bye</p>foo.”_ – why should anyone do that? Just _close_ your `p` before the `div`, which is the only thing that makes _sense_ here, and that whole problem is avoided in the first place. _“The first paragraph is closed implicitly before the DIV”_ – I’m aware of that … but without the _sloppiness_ of not closing elements where they should be closed you would not get into that mess in the first place. Leaving out closing `</p>`, even though allowed in most cases == bad advice IMHO.

Comment: What “other asides”? The question itself should contain enough code to reconstruct the problem. Links to live pages are *not* enough (and seldom useful), since they lose meaning once the problem has been fixed.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: The other asides in the linked-to jsfiddle. There are two very near the top.

Comment: @user2864740: On the contrary, CSS doesn't know or care whether the document it is styling is conformant. Most engines are implemented in such a way that selector matching is done on a per-element basis - the engine doesn't know that any given element matching an ID selector is unique, and cannot enforce it, so it errs on the side of caution and applies it anyway even if it's not.

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro How can *omitting an optional end-tag* such that the P is implicitly closed *per HTML since-forever rules* be "makes the code invalid"? It does not. HTML5 is not XML and a paragraph quite simply is not a general hierarchical container - XHTML tried to force that thinking, and failed.

Comment: It makes the code invalid because then you have a closing `</p>` without an opening `<p>`, that is invalid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @sdcr tells you in a comment, the issue is created because that `aside` in particular has a `p` element, and the space you see at the bottom is due to the `margin-bottom` of the paragraph.

To avoid seeing it, just remove the `margin-bottom` from the last paragraph in an `aside`:

```
aside p:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

See it working on an update of your jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tL4s1hjr/24/

Comment: Also, the reason the p margin is visible is because the border on the aside element prevents it from collapsing out of the aside.