# Why is my HTML closing span not being recognized in this one instance?

Tags: html, css

I have scads of places in my document where I use spans to enclose dialog, as can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/clayshannon/tL4s1hjr/105/)

But in one particular case, the closing span is not recognized, and the entire paragraph is seen as part of the section to be spanned. It is this, in the middle of chapter 24

### HTML

```
            <p><span class="dauphin" title="The Dauphin (the King) is speaking">"Kin any of you gentlemen tell me wher' Mr. Peter Wilks lives?"</span> they give a glance at one another, and nodded their heads, as much as to say,
```

'What d' I tell you?'  Then one of them says, kind of soft and gentle:

### CSS

```
.dauphin {
    color: orange;
}
```

If I pull just this HTML and CSS out and run it in a separate fiddle, it looks fine; it's just "in situ" that it fails; so here's some context:

```
            <p><span class="dauphin" title="The Dauphin (the King) is 
speaking">"If gentlemen kin afford to pay a dollar 
a mile apiece to be took on and put off in a yawl, a steamboat kin afford to 
carry 'em, can't it?"</span>
            </p>
            <p>So they softened down and said it was all right; and when we 
got to the village they yawled us ashore. 
About two dozen men flocked down when they see the yawl a-coming, and the
the king says:</p>
            <p><span class="dauphin" title="The Dauphin (the King) is spea
king">"Kin any of you gentlemen tell me wher' Mr. Peter Wilks lives?"</span> they7
 give a glance at one another, and nodded their heads, as much as to say
'What d' I tell you?'  Then one of them says, kind of soft and gentle:
            </p>
            <p><span class="others" title="Someone other than the primary
characters is speaking">"I'm sorry sir, but the best we can do is to tel
you where he <em>did</em> live yesterday evening."</span>
            </p>
```

Why does it fail, where hundreds of other usages of the same type work perfectly?

Comment: Have you tried HTML encoding strings before printing them?

Comment: You [have been told before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28788927/why-is-my-html-aside-block-adding-a-superfluous-ending-paragraph-break), that you should a) not dump such _vast_ examples here with a “you go figure out where my problem lies” attitude, and b) that you should go [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) your sh*t!

Comment: @CBroe This isn't a vast example, though.

Comment: @TylerH: The example code shown doesn’t reproduce the problem; the fiddle however, where we are supposed to look at it, is _massive_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked perfectly for me, same bunch of code.
[image: Input]
[image: Output]

Comment: Yeah, on the third or fourth try it finally did straighten up and fly right. Just one of those things, I reckon.